# Ошибка "No line found"

Tags: java, scanner

Текст ошибки:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line
>   found     at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)  at
>   Main.main(Main.java:58)

Код:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter;

public class Main {

    private static final String CSV_FILE = "track.csv";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("src/2016_11_02_01.txt");
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);

        /*Блок поиска начала информации о тегах*/
        int k = 0;//помогающая переменная
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        while (k == 0) {
            str = sc.nextLine();
            if (str.equals("// Информация по фрагменту")) {
                k = 1;
            }
        }
        /*Конец блока по поиску информации по фрагменту*/

        BufferedWriter writer = newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(CSV_FILE));
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("ID", "Name"));
        while (str.equals("// Информация по фрагменту")){
            /*Считываем информацию по фрагменту*/
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            name = name.substring(0, name.indexOf('<'));
            String time_plus = sc.nextLine();
            time_plus = time_plus.substring(0, time_plus.indexOf('<'));
            String length_ms = sc.nextLine();
            length_ms = length_ms.substring(0, length_ms.indexOf('<'));
            String length_uni = sc.nextLine();
            length_uni = length_uni.substring(0, length_uni.indexOf('<'));
            double length_unit = Double.valueOf(length_uni);
            /*Конец блока по считыванию информации*/

            String str_track = sc.nextLine();
            String[] str_tr;
            String delimeter = "\\t"; // Разделитель
            str_tr = str_track.split(delimeter); // Разделения строки str с помощью метода split
            csvPrinter.printRecord(str_tr[0], str_tr[1], str_tr[2], str_tr[3], str_tr[4], str_tr[5], str_tr[6], str_tr[7], str_tr[8], str_tr[9], str_tr[10]);
            while (length_unit != 0) {
                str_tr = sc.nextLine().split(delimeter);
                csvPrinter.printRecord(str_tr[0], str_tr[1], str_tr[2], str_tr[3], str_tr[4], str_tr[5], str_tr[6], str_tr[7], str_tr[8], str_tr[9], str_tr[10]);
                length_unit--;
            }
            sc.nextLine();
            str = sc.nextLine();
        }
            csvPrinter.flush();
    }
}
```

Проблема в конце while, не находится следующая строка. В текстовом файле она пустая, а затем идёт новая информация, которую как раз-таки мне надо получить. В чём ошибка? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Можно пример текстового файла

Comment: Честно говоря, в коде очень много странных пунктов. Имеет смысл наверное предоставить Ваш оригинальный txt файл.

Comment: @Mikita
Ссылка на текстовый файл: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/GcTL/acEBN3Fdc
А так, буду рада услышать честные комментарии.

Comment: ой... что-то устрашающее. А оригинальная задача как звучит? что сделать надо?

Comment: @MikitaBerazouski самое главное забыла написать)) Написать программу, которая создаёт csv-файл, в котором все фрагменты будут склеены в одну таблицу

Comment: @Vqq50 гляньте - вроде это то, что требуется.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходя из Ваших ответов, вот то, что даст результат... даже если вдруг это все же не то, что Вам надо, то код можно использовать как болванку.

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter;

public class Test {

    public static final String CSV_FILE = "track.csv";
    public static final String TXT_FILE = "src/2016_11_02_01.txt";
    public static final String STARTS_OF_FRAGMENT = "Время";
    public static final String DELIMETER = "\\t";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(TXT_FILE);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = null;

        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String nextLine = sc.nextLine();
            if (nextLine.startsWith(STARTS_OF_FRAGMENT)) {
                BufferedWriter writer = newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(CSV_FILE));
                csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(nextLine.split(DELIMETER)));
            } else if (csvPrinter != null) {
                csvPrinter.printRecord(nextLine.split("\\t"));
            }
        }
        csvPrinter.flush();
    }
}
```

В результате получим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Надеюсь я правильно понял задачу.

UPD после обсуждения в комментариях:

```
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Scanner;

import static java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedWriter;

public class Test {

    public static final String CSV_FILE = "track.csv";
    public static final String TXT_FILE = "src/2016_11_02_01.txt";
    public static final String STARTS_OF_FRAGMENT = "Время";
    public static final String DELIMETER = "\\t";
    public static final String TIME_OF_START = "Время начала фрагмента от начала исследования";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(TXT_FILE);
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
        CSVPrinter csvPrinter = null;
        BufferedWriter writer = newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(CSV_FILE));
        boolean isFirstFragment = true;
        BigDecimal time_plus = BigDecimal.ZERO;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String nextLine = sc.nextLine();

            if (nextLine.contains(TIME_OF_START)) {
                time_plus = new BigDecimal((nextLine.split(" "))[0]);
            } else if (nextLine.startsWith(STARTS_OF_FRAGMENT) && isFirstFragment) {
                csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader(nextLine.split(DELIMETER)));
                isFirstFragment = false;
            } else if (csvPrinter != null) {
                String[] split = nextLine.split("\\t");
                if (split[0].isEmpty()) {
                    time_plus = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                    continue;
                }

                try {
                    BigDecimal sumOfFragments = new BigDecimal(split[0]).add(time_plus);
                    split[0] = sumOfFragments.toString();
                    csvPrinter.printRecord(split);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        csvPrinter.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Всё так, только у вас получается, что на каждый фрагмент свой файл, а должно быть всё в одном, а в остальном, да, вы правы, а я намудрила...

Comment: А.. ну я думал, что файл конечный... но там уже легко. Выносите просто выше инициализацию BufferedWriter + поставьте проверку на заполнение header'a.

Comment: Окей, а если нужно, чтобы к 1-ому столбцу прибавлялось значение, данное в описании файлов, я правильно понимаю, что строки придётся тогда разбивать не в самой записи в файл, а ранее? 
Я пыталась это сделать, создав массив.

Comment: Приведите пример куда добавить и куда должно вставиться?

Comment: У нас 1 столбец состоит из времени(мс), к нему должно прибавляться значение времени из описания(у каждого фрагмента индивидуальный). Например:" 604776 <Время начала фрагмента от начала исследования, в мс>" - данный параметр у фрагмента, значит в 1 столбе должно быть вместо 0 - 604776, вместо 4 - 604780 и тд

Comment: да... все правильно... тогда надо разбивать чуть раньше - я обновил код

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78713/discussion-between-vqq50-and-mikita-berazouski).